# Angular material - form theme legacy not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I upgrade version angular from 14 to 15 and I use angular material ,in version 15 there are several new features in the component, I used the legacy version but I have a problem with font and forms that does not work well

code modules legacy:

```
            import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { MatLegacyTabsModule as MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-tabs';
        import { MatLegacyButtonModule as MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-button';
        import { MatLegacyProgressSpinnerModule as MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-progress-spinner';
        import { MatLegacyTooltipModule as MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-tooltip';
        import { MatLegacySelectModule as MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-select';
        import { MatLegacySlideToggleModule as MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-slide-toggle';
        import { MatLegacyInputModule as MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-input';
        import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
        import { MatLegacySnackBarModule as MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/legacy-snack-bar';
        import { MatLegacyRadioModule as MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-radio';
        import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
        import { MatLegacyFormFieldModule as MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-form-field';
        import { MatLegacyMenuModule as MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-menu';
        import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
        import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
        import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
        import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
        import { MAT_LEGACY_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MatLegacyDialogModule as MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-dialog';
        import { MatLegacyAutocompleteModule as MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-autocomplete';
        import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
        import { MatLegacyCardModule as MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-card';
        import { FormlyMaterialModule } from '@ngx-formly/material';
        import { MatLegacyTableModule as MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-table';
        import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
        import { MatLegacyPaginatorModule as MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-paginator';
        import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
        import { MatLegacyChipsModule as MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-chips';
        import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
        import { MatLegacyProgressBarModule as MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-progress-bar';
        import { MatLegacySliderModule as MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-slider';
        import { MatLegacyCheckboxModule as MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-checkbox';
        import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
        import { LegacyDateAdapter as DateAdapter, MAT_LEGACY_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_LEGACY_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/legacy-core';
        import { MultipleType } from '@Shared/enums/config.enum';
        
        const format = {
            parse: {
                dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            },
            display: {
                dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
                dateA11yLabel: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
            }
        };
        
        const modules = [
            MatTabsModule,
            MatSelectModule,
            MatSlideToggleModule,
            MatDatepickerModule,
            MatButtonModule,
            MatInputModule,
            MatSnackBarModule,
            MatProgressSpinnerModule,
            MatTooltipModule,
            MatRadioModule,
            MatStepperModule,
            MatFormFieldModule,
            MatMenuModule,
            MatDividerModule,
            MatGridListModule,
            MatToolbarModule,
            MatIconModule,
            MatAutocompleteModule,
            MatDialogModule,
            MatAutocompleteModule,
            MatExpansionModule,
            MatCardModule,
            FormlyMaterialModule,
            MatTableModule,
            MatPaginatorModule,
            MatBadgeModule,
            MatSortModule,
            MatChipsModule,
            MatButtonToggleModule,
            MatProgressBarModule,
            MatSliderModule,
            MatCheckboxModule
        ];
        
        @NgModule({
            imports: [
                ...modules
            ],
            exports: [
                ...modules,
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: MAT_LEGACY_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false} },
                { provide: MAT_LEGACY_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr' },
                { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_LEGACY_DATE_LOCALE] },
                { provide: MAT_LEGACY_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: format }
            ]
        })
        export class MaterialModule {
            constructor(private readonly adapter: DateAdapter<MultipleType>) {}
        
            french() {
                this.adapter.setLocale('fr');
            }
        
        }
```

code style.scss:

`         @use '@angular/material' as mat;

```
@include mat.legacy-core();

$md-test-blue: (50 : #e8eafe, 100 : #c5cbfe, 200 : #9fa9fd, 300 : #7987fc, 400 : #5c6dfb, 500 : #3f53fa, 600 : #394cf9, 700 : #3142f9, 800 : #2939f8, 900 : #1b29f6, A100 : #ffffff, A200 : #f6f7ff, A400 : #c3c7ff, A700 : #aaaeff,
    contrast: (50 : #000000, 100 : #000000, 200 : #000000, 300 : #000000, 400 : #ffffff, 500 : #ffffff, 600 : #ffffff, 700 : #ffffff, 800 : #ffffff, 900 : #ffffff, A100 : #000000, A200 : #000000, A400 : #000000, A700 : #000000)
);
$md-test-red: (50 : #fde5e9, 100 : #fbbdc8, 200 : #f891a4, 300 : #f56580, 400 : #f34464, 500 : #f12349, 600 : #ef1f42, 700 : #ed1a39, 800 : #eb1531, 900 : #e70c21, A100 : #ffffff, A200 : #ffdee0, A400 : #ffabb1, A700 : #ff9199,
contrast: (50 : #000000, 100 : #000000, 200 : #000000, 300 : #000000, 400 : #ffffff, 500 : #ffffff, 600 : #ffffff, 700 : #ffffff, 800 : #ffffff, 900 : #ffffff, A100 : #000000, A200 : #000000, A400 : #000000, A700 : #000000)
);
@import "./mixins.scss";

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

:root {
  --primary-color: #F12349;
  --accent-color: #3F53FA;
  --nav-color1: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
  --nav-color2: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  --white-background: #ffffff;
  --input-border-style: solid;
  --input-border-width: 1px;
  --input-border-untouched-color: #868898;
  --input-border-touched-color: #5264FA;
  --input-border-invalid-color: red;
  --input-border-radius: 4px;
  --input-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(73,86,92,0.12), 0 0 4px 0 rgba(73,86,92,0.1);

}


$test-font-family: "'sofia-pro', sans-serif";
$typography-levels: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(
  $font-family: "'sofia-pro', sans-serif"
);
$typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-config($test-font-family);

$test-primary: mat.define-palette($md-test-blue);
$test-accent: mat.define-palette($md-test-red);

$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
    color: (
        primary: $rexmat-primary,
        accent: $rexmat-accent
    ),
    typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-config( $font-family: "'sofia-pro', sans-serif"),
));

@include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($theme);

@import './test-theme.scss';

/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
```

`

code angular.json:

`"styles": [ "./node_modules/@angular/material/legacy-prebuilt-themes/legacy-indigo-pink.css", "src/styles.scss" ],`

code in my project now:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqg9A.png)

example of output in project after migration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1BHG.png)

code in my project before migration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGZSz.png)

example of output in project before migration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBQgl.png)

the problem now that I use the legacy version after the migration but in the forms classes apply the new angular hardware class 15,

class mat-mdc doesn't exist in version legacy but in code html exist, I don't khnow where is exact the error in my code or in configuration

Comment: Maybe your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101022/angular-material-15-styles-for-legacy-components

Comment: @DiogoMachado I already applied this but it doesn't work

Comment: Another suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284868/after-upgrade-from-angular-14-to-15-my-ui-is-not-shown-properly?noredirect&#x3D;1#comment136283865_77284868

Comment: @DiogoMachado in file style.scss I add all code legacy and I add code in answer but doesn't work

Comment: If you want help, you should clarify what is not working. Also make sure you understand how to migrate to v15: [Migrating to MDC-based Angular Material Components](https://v15.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration)